# How to apply JSON data from other site to my form autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have input form using a codeigniter and I want to get my autocomplete from the json data of the other site but it seems it's not working.

I apply this code below:

MY JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var options = {
    url: "http://duaa.ae/location-en.json", 
    listLocation: "label","desc",
    matchResponseProperty: "label"
};

$("#response-async").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

MY PHP/HTML

```
<script src="assets/js/autocomplete/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/autocomplete/easy-autocomplete.min.js">

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label"><?php echo lang('Address') ?></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <?php echo form_input('address', set_value('address', $estate['address']), 'class="form-control" id="response-async" placeholder="' . lang('Address') . '"') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Site where I get JSON file 
[here](http://duaa.ae/location-en.json)

Note I use this [guide](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide)

Comment: Are you sure that you can get json with ajax?

Comment: doesn't seem that site allows you to "borrow" their data (i.e., no CORS headers apparent)